# Symfony. How do I pass parameters to Custom Form Field Type?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have created Custom Form Field Type according to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/create_custom_field_type.html) and it works fine(I mean no errors). I have a class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class RangeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(

        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return RangeType::class;
    }
}
```

I have a twig template:

```
{# app/Resources/views/form/fields.html.twig #}
{% block range_widget %}
   <div class="cell-md-12 offset-top-45 offset-md-top-0">
      <div data-min="" data-max="6000" data-start="[9, 2999]" data-step="10" data-tooltip="false" data-min-diff="10" data-input=".rd-range-input-value-2" data-input-2=".rd-range-input-value-3" class="rd-range"></div>
      <hr class="divider divider-offset-lg divider-gray veil reveal-md-block">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I added that to the config:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'form/fields.html.twig'
```

and finally I have a code to add the field to the form:

```
$builder->add('price', RangeType::class, [
                'data'   => $options['priceRange'] ? $options['priceRange'] : $options['minPrice'].",".$options['maxPrice'],
                'attr'=> [
                    'data-min' => $options['minPrice'],
                    'data-max' => $options['maxPrice'],
                    'data-dimension' => $options['dimension']
                ]
            ]);
```

How do I use that "data", "data-min", "data-max", "data-dimension" options from the form builder in the twig template? So far as you can see all of them are static in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access you 'attr' option values by using the folowing path:

```
form.vars.attr
```

So, to get the 'data-min' parameter value form example, you'll just need to do:

```
{% set attr = form.vars.attr %}
<div data-min="{{ attr['data-min'] }}" ...
```